# Creating Results Table in R?

Tags: r

I want to present my regression (zero-inflated negative binomial regression) results in a table created from R.

Please find my regression code and output below.

```
    regression_model <- zeroinfl(
      malaria_cases  ~  District + population + elevation_google,
      data = full_malaria_data,
      dist = "negbin",
      control=zeroinfl.control(maxit = 100000),
      na.action = na.fail
    )


Output: 
Count model coefficients (negbin with log link):
                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)         1.225e+00  2.532e-01   4.839 1.31e-06 ***
DistrictCanta Galo  4.245e-01  3.467e-01   1.225  0.22072    
DistrictCaue       -2.345e+00  8.765e-01  -2.675  0.00748 ** 
DistrictLemba       9.969e-01  3.809e-01   2.617  0.00886 ** 
DistrictLobata      4.635e-01  3.253e-01   1.425  0.15429    
DistrictMe Zochi   -5.823e-02  3.046e-01  -0.191  0.84838    
population          6.752e-04  8.941e-05   7.552 4.28e-14 ***
elevation_google   -4.487e-03  1.025e-03  -4.376 1.21e-05 ***
Log(theta)         -6.108e-01  1.444e-01  -4.230 2.34e-05 ***

Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)        -1.451501   3.461808  -0.419   0.6750  
DistrictCanta Galo  2.164011   3.367402   0.643   0.5205  
DistrictCaue        3.956067   3.556434   1.112   0.2660  
DistrictLemba       1.437854   3.431202   0.419   0.6752  
DistrictLobata      1.246697   3.477836   0.358   0.7200  
DistrictMe Zochi    2.184260   3.397761   0.643   0.5203  
population         -0.007229   0.003045  -2.374   0.0176 *
elevation_google    0.001928   0.001748   1.103   0.2700  
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Theta = 0.5429 
Number of iterations in BFGS optimization: 32 
Log-likelihood: -691.3 on 17 Df
```

Comment: You could use `tab_model` function from `sjPlot` package

Comment: it is more imporant where and how would you like to present it. Package `stargazer` allows you to create nice latex and HTML ready tables: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/vignettes/stargazer.pdf

Comment: also `broom` + `huxtable` packages ...